# Norm of $A$ is zer0 when $\Bbb H$ is Complex Hiblert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

If $\Bbb H$ is a $\Bbb C$-Hilbert space and $A\in \Bbb B(\Bbb H),$i.e. bounded linear operator on $\Bbb H$ such that $\langle Ah,h\rangle=0$ for all h in $\Bbb H$, then $A=0$

For the proof of this proposition, why we don't need the extra assumption $A=A^*?$ When I have this extra assumption I know $\|A\|=\sup\{|\langle Ah,h \rangle: \|h\|=1\}$, then done very easily.
Could you please help me?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

First note that if $\langle Ah, h'\rangle=0$ for all $h,h'\in\mathbb H$ then $A=0$. Recall the polarization identity $$\langle h,h'\rangle=\frac{1}{4}(\langle h+h',h+h'\rangle - \langle h-h',h-h'\rangle +\langle h+ih',h+ih'\rangle-\langle h-ih',h-ih'\rangle$$
It follows from the first observation and the polarization identity that $\langle Ah,h\rangle=0$ for all $h$ implies $A=0$.

Comment: could you please explain little bit what is polarization identity?

Comment: how to prove the first condition to use polarization identity?